# Django Detail view doesn't work

Tags: django, django-templates

This is my detail_veiw.html

```
{% extends 'mysite/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="post">

    <div class="date">
        {{ post.pub_date }}
    </div>

    <h1>{{ post.product }}</h1>
    <p>{{ post.description|linebreaksbr }}</p>

</div>
{% endblock %}

<a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_edit' pk=post.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
```

So...what I intended was to show pub_date, product, description 
However, below is the screenshot of Detail_view of Post
As you can see I only show pub_date...

[image: Screenshot]

This is how detail_views looks like

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'mysite/post_detail.html', {'post':Post})
```

Comment: probably `product` and `description` attributes are None?

Comment: How can I know that product and description attributes are None?

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you can add the views.py also.

The template code seems to be good. To check the values for the Product and description you can visit your project admin site or you can use any Database GUI tools depending up on what you are using.

Few of the Tools might be [Pgadmin2](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/) for PostgreSQL, [Toad](https://software.dell.com/products/toad-for-oracle/) for Orcale or you can use something like [Datagrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) by Jetbrains which supports variety of Databases.

But if you are not comfortable using these then the best way is to login to your admin page for your Project if you have already registed the Product Model with admin then you can see on the admin page or else check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial02/#creating-an-admin-user) one on how to add your models to admin page and creating a new admin if haven't created admin role.

Comment: Product and description are not None

Comment: def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'mysite/post_detail.html', {'post':Post})

Comment: The problem is you are passing class name "Post" rather than the object "post" to the render function.  Trying changing that to return render(request, 'mysite/post_detail.html', {'post':post})